# Twilio Javascript Function to Parse Array

Tags: javascript, twilio

I have a twilio Javascript function that gets executed in my studio flow immediately after somebody calls the associated studio flow phone #.  This function is supposed to check if there is a currently active conference call going on and return either "True" or "False" so that I can then use that string in an if/else widget to either connect the caller OR initiate a new conference.

```
    // This is your new function. To start, set the name and path on the left.

exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
  
    var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.withCredentials = true;
    
xhr.open("GET", "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/myAccountSid/Conferences.json?FriendlyName=mySidDocumentName");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic myAuthString");
xhr.send();

    xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
        if(this.readyState == 4) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(xhr.responseText));
            var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            var arrayLength = Object.keys(jsonResponse.Conferences[jsonResponse]).length;
            if (arrayLength > 0) {
              var isConferenceOngoing = "True"
            } else {
              var isConferenceOngoing = "False"
            }
        }
        return callback(null, isConferenceOngoing);
    });
};
```

The "conferences" key that I am interested in, in the response, is an array and that causes a problem because Twilio can not parse an array in the studio flow, so it has to be done in the function call: https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/http-request "Note that, although an array is valid JSON, if your request returns an array of objects, it will not be parsed."

So all I simply need to check for is whether or not the Conferences array is empty and if so return "False" to my studio flow OR if there is an active conference (i.e. the array length is > 0) then return "True".  Returning either "True" or "False" will allow me to do an if/else widget in my studio flow to either connect the caller to the existing conference or start a new conference call.

Here is what the response looks like in Postman when there is not an active conference call (notice the conferences array is empty):
[image]

My knowledge of Javascript is next to zero, but I think I am close.

Answer (score 0):

Update: Added async/await functions based on comments.

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
      
const twilioClient = context.getTwilioClient();

let responseObject = twilioClient.conferences
      .list({status: 'in-progress'})
 
var isConferenceOngoing = null     
  
async function setConferenceVariable() {  
      if (responseObject.Length > 0)
      {
            isConferenceOngoing = "True"
      } else {
            isConferenceOngoing = "False"
      }
}

async function getConferenceDetails() {
     await setConferenceVariable();
     return callback(null, isConferenceOngoing);
}
getConferenceDetails()
};
```

Latest Update: Simpler method below.

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
    const twilioClient = context.getTwilioClient();
    twilioClient.conferences
        .list({status: 'in-progress'})
        .then(conferences => { callback(null, !conferences.length)})
};
```

Comment: Not sure that will consistently work, your callback is not in the right place @dylan, https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/functions/invocation#callback-and-asynchronous-limitations (since it returns a promise, you will need to await)

Comment: I edited the code to include async/await functions.  Please let me know if this looks good.

Answer (score 0):

Latest update looks much better @dylan. I am not seeing a return value when false, so did this:

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
    const twilioClient = context.getTwilioClient();
    twilioClient.conferences
        .list({status: 'in-progress'})
        .then(conferences => callback(null, {result: !conferences.length}))
        .catch(err => callback(err));
};
```

Comment: Can you elaborate?  !array should return True if the array is empty, but False if it is not empty.  Not saying you are wrong, but it is difficult for me to test with only one phone number when I need 3.

Comment: I think it has to do with returning a boolean false in the callback is having some type of funky effect, as nothing is returned.